# Copy field from one table to another with REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, etl

Before running a `REGEXP_REPLACE` on a big table, I want to preview the results, so I want to copy the 'before' and 'after' of the modified field to another table so I can audit.

What's the best way to do this?

Something like

```sql
INSERT INTO table2 (before, after)
SELECT field1, REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')
FROM table1
WHERE condition
```

(MariaDB)

Comment: Then just simply run a `SELECT field1, REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')
FROM table1
WHERE condition` without the INSERT wrapper and you will see the before column value and the after column value. this way you dont need a dummy table

Comment: @RiggsFolly Of course, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were my project I'd do these things.

First. Just do this and eyeball the results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), field1, REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar') 
  FROM table1
 WHERE field1 <> REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')
 GROUP BY field1, REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')
 ORDER BY COUNT(*), field1
```

That will show you the least frequent values first so you can see the one-off problems caused by your replace first. No need to create a table.

Second, I'd eyeball the values that DIDN'T change with this, changing the WHERE clause from `<>` to `=`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), field1 
  FROM table1
 WHERE field1 = REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')
 GROUP BY field1
 ORDER BY COUNT(*), field1
```

Maybe some stuff didn't change that should have.

**Edit**  SQL can get a little verbose. If you're fiddling around with some complex conversion functions you might try creating a view. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW testview AS
SELECT field1, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar') changed
  FROM table1;
```

Then you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*), field1, changed 
  FROM testview
 WHERE field1 <> changed
 GROUP BY field1, changed
 ORDER BY COUNT(*), field1;
```

And similar queries.  If you must change your replace function, you can edit the view definition and do the CREATE OR REPLACE again.

Comment: I like it! Is there a way to replace the 3 occurrences of the same function `REGEXP_REPLACE(field1,'foo','bar')` with some kind of alias or function?